# 1980s Floral Punk (?) Violent Cottage Core Children's Book

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I remember distinctly this children's book in my church library growing up, this is late 80s early 90s that had this floral punk aesthetic. Periscopes made to mimic crocuses and lilies in burrows behind enemy lines where spies recorded enemy activities, domesticated bugs helping out in various ways... there was basically a cottage core aesthetic group in conflict with this industrialize and pollute the earth group of rodent size hippo type creatures. It was a highly detailed picture book, eye-spy tons of cool little details on each page one wanted to come through, with pretty dense text... so an older child's book right before one would go on to books without pictures every page and chapter books.

Anyone have any clue what the name of this book might be?

Comment: Floral *punk*??

Answer (score 15):

This is *Trouble for Trumpets* by Peter Cross and Peter Dallas Smith (1982).

From a [review](https://www.publishersweekly.com/9780679803430): "Fanciful creatures called Trumpets are besieged by their sworn enemies, the Grumpets in this lavishly illustrated allegory of war and peace. Ages 8-up. (July)"

But the pics will be the sure-fire confirmation:

[image: trees and Trumpets]

[image: guns]

[image: Cover]

[image: Inside tunnels]

Comment: +1 Aside: The Trumpets look like physical [Moomintroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Moomin_characters#Moomintroll) rip-offs!